# dynamically setting __webpack_public_path__ does not work after build in vue application

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I have a vue frontend, and spring boot backend application.
My application has multiple instances with different url paths (for example /instance1, /instance2), but uses the same build project - meaning every instances runs the same jar.
Also the application serves static files - the index.html of the compiled vue application.

My problem is that the vue application needs to know dynamically from which url path to get all its static files, so for example when i get the index.html of instance1 it need to get all the assets from /instance1/assets

I read many answers to this problem which they all suggested basically to configure dynamically the **webpack_public_path** global variable like [this first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55955113/is-this-possible-to-configure-publicpath-in-vue-cli-dynamically-in-runtime#)

so in my vue app I did this:

in `main.js` file:

```js
import './publicpath'
import Vue from 'vue'
```

then in `publicpath.js` file:

```js
__webpack_public_path__ = `/${window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]}/`
```

**The problem** with the answer linked above is that it only works for me when I run the application as a dev application (when running `npm run serve` on vue project). This doesn't work after **building** the project, and the build index.html is served by spring boot.

I couldn't find any answer that solved this problem so I would really appreciate any help

Thank you!

Comment: Show us some code pls...

Comment: Hi I added some code now :)

Comment: That leading slash seems wrong. Just open the Dev Tools here on this page and try to paste it to the console...it will give you `"/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/"`

Comment: I changed the code and it still doesn’t work. The point is not the logic of the code, even if I’ll put simple string there, it won’t use it as publicPath after building the project and serving its index.html.

Comment: Are you using Vue router ?

Comment: Yes, why? is it related?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Changing `__webpack_public_path__` may not to be enough....

### Why

Vue CLI has a [publicPath](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) option:

> By default, Vue CLI assumes your app will be deployed at the root of a domain, e.g. `https://www.my-app.com/`. If your app is deployed at a sub-path, you will need to specify that sub-path using this option. For example, if your app is deployed at `https://www.foobar.com/my-app/`, set `publicPath` to `'/my-app/'`

This value is used in multiple places:

1. To configure Webpack - set it's [output.publicPath](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/) [option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputpublicpath).

The value is important both at build time and runtime.

At runtime it is made available as a global JS variable `__webpack_public_path__` and used (by Webpack) when creating URL's for any module requests (loading dynamic JS chunks, referencing images etc.)

At build time, it is also used for creating URL's but this time for the assets which are needed to load your app into the browser - all the `<link>` and `<script>` tags responsible to load all JavaScript and CSS of your app. Those are directly injected into the `index.html` as **hardcoded strings**

2. The value is made available as an ENV variable `process.env.BASE_URL` usable inside your code. This variable is very useful

For example Vue-router, also [requires some configuration](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base) to work correctly when the app is not hosted in server root (because its responsible for creating URL's for `<router-link>`). This is most of the time done using this line in it's config: `base: process.env.BASE_URL`

Or you may need to configure base url for Axios to make API calls...

All of this works thanks to Webpack's [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/). And really important thing to understand is how it works. Anytime you use `process.env.BASE_URL` in your code, Webpack replaces that string with configured value **during build time** (ie. there is no variable `process.env.BASE_URL` know at runtime)

### How

From all the above it should be clear now that just replacing the value of `__webpack_public_path__` at runtime as suggested by [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55955113/is-this-possible-to-configure-publicpath-in-vue-cli-dynamically-in-runtime#) is just not enough. So what else is needed?

1. Do not use `process.env.BASE_URL` anywhere in your code. Using `__webpack_public_path__` instead should be enough to solve this problem
2. Much bigger problem are the links in `index.html` generated during build time. Those are clearly not affected by `__webpack_public_path__` variable. Only option I see here is to set `publicPath` for production build to some unique value and instead of serving `index.html` as a static file, serve it as dynamic response - reading file from the disk, replacing original `publicPath` value with correct value (for the specific deployment) and serving the result

### Alternatives

1. First and obvious alternative is just to setup multiple CI/CD pipelines, configure `publicPath` for each using ENV variables and build separate package for each instance
2. Second alternative is hinted in Vue CLI [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath)

> The value (`publicPath`) can also be set to an empty string (`''`) or a relative path (`./`) so that all assets are linked using relative paths. This allows the built bundle to be deployed under any public path, or used in a file system based environment like a Cordova hybrid app.

The point is if your site uses relative link without leading slash, it should be interpreted by the browser as a path relative to the current path ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21828923/381282)) and as a result, you can deploy under any public path...

The decision is yours as only you know the details needed to make one...

Comment: So how can I change the vue publicPath dynamically?
My app is not loaded when I serve the build index.html file because it doesn't know the path to access the static files, including the js files.

Comment: There is **no way** to change Vue CLI option `publicPath` at runtime. See my updated answer

Comment: Thank you so much for that detailed answer! I will try a few options and update what worked best for me

Comment: So what worked for me is to use vue-cli relative option: so in ```vue.js.config``` I set ```publicPath: './'``` which tells vue to get all the assets from the relative path of the url. So thank you very much!

Comment: Spot on with all of this -- I'll add that there may well be additional plugins which further complicate things. Using server-side templates and setting the vue publicPath to `{{assetRoot}}` I was able to get part of it working, but unless I process *all* static files I still have issues from e.g. the PWA plugin as well as some others -- and that prevents me from precompressing the static assets.

Definitely a convoluted issue

Comment: Alternative 1 is really poor practice (I think). Alternative 2 works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Vue router, you can use the `base` parameter in the constructor argument to set a custom path:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: `/${window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]}/`,
  routes
})
```